# Invoke-WebRequest with dynamic host fails

Tags: powershell, httpwebrequest

I want to execute a web request with host defined by a parameter:

```
$serverHost = "myhost"
Invoke-WebRequest http://$serverHost:1234/service -Method Get
```

Powershell complains about this with the following error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value "http:///service" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

What do I have to do to get PowerShell to correctly interpret my URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell simply does not resolve the variable within your URL. You are trying to query the service at the URI `http://$serverHost:1234/service` which won't work. You could do

```
$serverHost = "myHost"
$service = "http://$serverHost`:1234/service"
Invoke-WebRequest $service -Method Get
```

(please note that the Backtick ` is required in order to escape the colon).

Comment: So is it impossible to do without creating the new variable `$service`?  I can't make the variable substitution "inline"?

Comment: Actually I do not know. I did try to surround the while URI-Part with quotes and it did not work either. Maybe there is a solution I just don't know.

Answer (score 3):

The colon, when used with variables, is PowerShells way of [setting the scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) of that variable. It is also used when calling providers like `$env:path`. That is what PowerShell is seeing here. It thinks your trying to call the variable `1234` in the `$serverHost` scope.

That is why in your error it states it could not find the host `http:///service` since that variable previously described does not exist.

Backtick to escape the character would work. As well as using the format operator or curly braces or a subexpression. All designed to isolate the colon from the variable in this case.

```
("http://{0}:1234/service" -f $serverHost)
"http://${serverHost}:1234/service"
"http://$($serverHost):1234/service"
```

Any of those would work inline with the `Invoke-WebRequest` call. Make sure you keep the parenthesis around the `-f` call.